# Dynamic parsing of .proto text file at runtime to generate descriptors

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, protoc, proto3

I am currently working on Google Protocol Buffers and need to generate dynamic messages. I already have my .proto files defined as shown below.

```
message TSInbound
{
  string id = 1;
  map<string,string> state = 2;
  map<string,string> reading =3;
}
```

AFAIK,I can use File Descriptor Set to create dynamic messsages. But, that would involve using the compiler to generate the desc files. I would like to generate Descriptor without compiling the .proto files. Is there a way for dynamic creation of message using custom defined .proto files and not using protoc ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you are asking: "Is there a way to dynamically parse text `.proto` files at runtime to get descriptors."

The `.proto` parser is written in C++. It is available as the library `libprotoc.so`. You could, in theory, write a JNI wrapper around this to do parsing at runtime. However, there is no (official) pure-Java parser for `.proto` files.

Comment: Yes,@kenton Varda that is what I precisely want to do. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @Ankita Did you find any solution for the above problem?

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution from confluent, more precisely 'io.confluent:kafka-protobuf-serializer', which enables this in a very easy way

```
    ProtobufSchema schema = new ProtobufSchema(
            Files.readString(
                    Path.of("/anyPath/test.proto")
            )
    );
    Descriptor descriptor = schema.toDescriptor();
    Message deserializedMessage = DynamicMessage.parseFrom(descriptor, messageByteArr);
```